# How to increase dmesg buffer size in CentOs 7.2?

Tags: centos, dmesg

I am getting following message in dmesg:

```
"systemd-journald[414]: /dev/kmsg buffer overrun, some messages lost."
```

How to increase dmesg log buffer size to view all debug messages?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to append:

```
log_buf_len=<size>
```

To your grub line.

in other words, edit `/etc/default/grub` so that the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap"
```

Becomes:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap log_buf_len=5M"
```

*Change `5M` to whatever size you require*

Then run:

```
grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

To regenerate grub.