# Dmesg ring buffer overload problem

Tags: linux, drivers, devices, usb-device, dmesg

I am writing a device driver. I need to seek in system logs; for that I use `dmesg`. In my case `dmesg` is overloaded with these warnings:

```
[ 5578.052140] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[ 5578.052146] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[ 5578.057805] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[ 5578.057871] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[ 5578.057872] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ 5578.057873] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
```

Because of `dmesg` overload, my intended messages are not available. I want the way to read my kernel log or block these pcieport logs.
So what can I do to read my intended messages?

Comment: How about `dmesg | grep -v pcieport`? Or perhaps you have to [increase the buffer size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412182/how-to-increase-dmesg-buffer-size-in-centos-7-2).

Answer (score 0):

Those messages are generated by PCIE Advanced Error Reporting: kernel configuration item `CONFIG_PCIEAER`.

If you are using a custom kernel, disable that in your kernel configuration.
Otherwise, add the `noaer` boot option to your kernel command line to disable AER without recompiling the kernel, and reboot.

With a bit of Googling, I found [a discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255722) mentioning that using the `pcie_aspm=off` kernel boot option may also help. But try `noaer` first, as it's more specific and `pcie_aspm=off` might be overkill if `noaer` is sufficient.